# gluNewQuadric() before opengl's initialization

Tags: c++, opengl, initialization, sdl

I'm working on a c++ code that uses SDL/opengl.

Is this possible to create a pointer to a quadric with `gluNewQuadric()` before having initialized opengl with `SDL_SetVideoMode`?

The idea is to create a class with a (pointer to a) quadric class member that has to be instantiate before the `SDL_SetVideoMode` call. This pointer is initialized in the class' constructor with a `gluNewQuadric()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything in the [source code](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/glu/sgi/libutil/quad.c#n54) that would require an active GL context.